# Docker cache-from not all layers being run if no files have changed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've added a simple repo that recreates this issue: https://github.com/cgreening/docker-cache-problem

We have a very simple Dockerfile.

To speed up our builds we're using the `--cache-from` directive and using a previous build as a cache.

We're seeing some weird behaviour where if the files have not changed the lines after the COPY line are not being run.

```
RUN yarn && yarn build
```

Does not seem to get executed so when the application tries to start `node_modules` is missing.

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn && yarn build

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "start"]
```

We're deploying to Kubernetes but I can pull the image locally and see that the files are missing:

```
# docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash gcr.io/XXXXX
root@3561a9cdab6e:/app# ls
DEVELOPING.md  Dockerfile  Makefile  README.md  admin-tools  app.dev.yaml  jest.config.js  package.json  src  tailwind.config.js  tools  tsconfig.json  tslint.json  yarn.lock
root@3561a9cdab6e:/app#
```

Edit:

I've managed to recreate the problem outside of our build system.

Initial build:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t gcr.io/XXX/test:a .  --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1
docker push gcr.io/XXX/test:a
```

All works - node_modules and build folder are there:

Clean up docker as if we starting from scratch like on the build system

```
docker system prune -a
```

Do another build:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t gcr.io/XXX/test:b . --cache-from gcr.io/XXX/test:a --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1
docker push gcr.io/XXX/test:a
```

Everything is still fine.

Clean up docker as if we starting from scratch like on the build system

```
docker system prune -a
```

Do a third build:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t gcr.io/XXX/test:c . --cache-from gcr.io/XXX/test:b --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1
```

Files are missing!

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash gcr.io/topo-wme-dev-d725ec6e/test:c
root@d07f6f1d3b12:/app# ls
DEVELOPING.md  Dockerfile  Makefile  README.md  admin-tools  app.dev.yaml  coverage  jest.config.js  package.json  src  tailwind.config.js  tools  tsconfig.json  tslint.json  yarn.lock
```

No node_modules or build folder.

Comment: What command are you using to spin up your container?

Comment: We're deploying to Kubernetes, but I can pull down a built image and see that the files are missing. I can also run the image locally and see the problem. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why not clean-build using a multi-stage build? I haven't used docker with node-js yet, but with bigger c++ projects we usually prepare a base-image, install and compile our dependencies and then from there we go to the next stage where we get the code and build it. Would that work for you?

Comment: We have multiple projects in a mono repo - when deploying they all get rebuilt, but many of them have not actually changed. Using the cache was an attempt to speed up the build process. The builds are all happening in GitHub actions so it's pretty slow to pull everything and then run all the various package installs.